# Excel: use formula in cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel: use formula in cell format](https://superuser.com/questions/334330/excel-use-formula-in-cell-format)

Is there a way to use a formula as a cell format?

AFAIK, conditional formatting allows only static format applied based on some condition. I want the format itself to be dynamic. For example, I want to set the color of a cell to be its content (if the cell value is "red" then use red as the color), without setting a conditional formatting rule per each color.